# Getting HTTPS to Work with WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I am trying connect to wcf service. I dont have access to it. It has credentials and SSL (https).

```
        try
        {
            var stub = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
            stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
            stub.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";
            stub.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.PeerOrChainTrust;
            stub.getData("Test");
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
        }
```

app.config:

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService">
            <security mode="Transport">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" />
            </security>
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="https://address/path/service.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Error I got:

An error occurred while making the HTTP request to https://address/path/Service.svc. This should be due to the fact that the server certificate is not configured properly with HTTP.SYS in the HTTPS case. This could also be caused by a mismatch of the security binding between the client and the server.

What I am doing wrong??? Do I need something add to app.config?? I guess that something with certificate is not good???

Comment: Are you sure about what are you doing with this line: `stub.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate...`? Does it work without it?

Comment: I also tried without. Same result